# MYSQL inner join 2nd table sort most recent

Tags: mysql, join, select, inner-join

I have 2 tables `categories` and `equipment`.

When selecting  I wanted to group by categories and show the most recent equipment in that category, however my query will only return the first equipment in that category.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT C.*, E.`photos` AS `photos`, E.`name` AS ename, E.`url` AS `eurl` FROM `categories` AS C INNER JOIN `equipment` E ON C.id=E.category WHERE C.`offon`=1 GROUP BY `category` ORDER BY C.`name` ASC, E.`date_added` DESC
```

I have tried `JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` and `date_added ASC` but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a join with the subquer for max date

```
SELECT C.*
    , E.`photos` AS `photos`
    , E.`name` AS ename
    , E.`url` AS `eurl` 
FROM `categories` AS C 
INNER JOIN `equipment` E ON C.id=E.category  and  C.`offon`=1 
inner join  (
  select category , max(`date_added`) max_date
  from  `equipment` 
  group by category 

) t on t.max_date = E.date_added and C.id=E.category
```